# 2D Iterative Closest Point (ICP) in Python

Tags: python, point-clouds

I am learning the ICP algorithm and have some confusion during implementing a simple 2D ICP in Python. I use ICP to estimate the transform between two curves while the point correspondences are given.

I found if I don't add transformation mat **t** to the results, the results are pretty good. However, if I add **t**, there will be a gap between two curves.

I am very confused about this problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Original points
[image: original points]

Without add t to results
[image: without add t to results]

Add t to results
[image: add t to results]

This is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# icp_known_corresp: performs icp given that the input datasets
# are aligned so that Line1(:, QInd(k)) corresponds to Line2(:, PInd(k))
def icp_known_corresp(Line1, Line2, QInd, PInd):
    Q = Line1[:, QInd]
    P = Line2[:, PInd]

    MuQ = compute_mean(Q)
    MuP = compute_mean(P)

    W = compute_W(Q, P, MuQ, MuP)

    [R, t] = compute_R_t(W, MuQ, MuP)

    # Compute the new positions of the points after
    # applying found rotation and translation to them
    NewLine = R @ P

    # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
    # If i don't add t to the NewLine the results are good. #
    # If i add t, there will be a gap between two curves.   #
    # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
    
    #NewLine[0, :] += t[0]
    #NewLine[1, :] += t[1]

    E = compute_error(Q, NewLine)
    return [NewLine, E]

# compute_W: compute matrix W to use in SVD
def compute_W(Q, P, MuQ, MuP):
    Q[0, :] -= MuQ[0]
    Q[1, :] -= MuQ[1]
    P[0, :] -= MuP[0]
    P[1, :] -= MuP[1]
    return Q @ P.T


# compute_R_t: compute rotation matrix and translation vector
# based on the SVD as presented in the lecture
def compute_R_t(W, MuQ, MuP):
    U,S,V = np.linalg.svd(W)
    R = U @ V 
    t = MuQ - R @ MuP
    return [R, t]

# compute_mean: compute mean value for a [M x N] matrix
def compute_mean(M):
    return np.mean(M, axis = 1)

# compute_error: compute the icp error
def compute_error(Q, OptimizedPoints):
    E = Q - OptimizedPoints
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(E**2))

# simply show the two lines
def show_figure(Line1, Line2):
    plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(Line1[0], Line1[1], marker='o', s=2, label='Line 1')
    plt.scatter(Line2[0], Line2[1], s=1, label='Line 2')

    plt.xlim([-8, 8])
    plt.ylim([-8, 8])
    plt.legend()  

    plt.show()


# initialize figure
def init_figure():
    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.show()
    fig.canvas.draw()

    line1_fig = plt.scatter([], [], marker='o', s=2, label='Line 1')
    line2_fig = plt.scatter([], [], marker='o', s=1, label='Line 2')
    # plt.title(title)
    plt.xlim([-8, 8])
    plt.ylim([-8, 8])
    plt.legend()

    return fig, line1_fig, line2_fig


# update_figure: show the current state of the lines
def update_figure(fig, line1_fig, line2_fig, Line1, Line2, hold=False):
    line1_fig.set_offsets(Line1.T)
    line2_fig.set_offsets(Line2.T)
    if hold:
        plt.show()
    else:
        fig.canvas.flush_events()
        fig.canvas.draw()
        plt.pause(0.5)


Data = np.load('icp_data.npz')
Line1 = Data['LineGroundTruth']
Line2 = Data['LineMovedCorresp']

# Show the initial positions of the lines
show_figure(Line1, Line2)


# We assume that the there are 1 to 1 correspondences for this data
QInd = np.arange(len(Line1[0]))
PInd = np.arange(len(Line2[0]))

# Perform icp given the correspondences
[Line2, E] = icp_known_corresp(Line1, Line2, QInd, PInd)

# Show the adjusted positions of the lines
show_figure(Line1, Line2)

# print the error
print('Error value is: ', E)
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across your question during researching about ICP for 2D problems.

The algorithm itself is correct, however your implementation changes the original data.

If you replace

```
W = compute_W(Q, P, MuQ, MuP)
```

With

```
W = compute_W(Q, P.copy(), MuQ, MuP)
```

Then you will see the expected behavior.
During this `compute_W` step you already add the `t` vector in the original Data because you modify it.